# SymPy: simplifying of inverse function

Tags: python-2.7, sympy

I define 2 sympy functions **f**, **g**, s.t. **g** is inverse of **f**:

```
import sympy as sy

g = sy.Function('g')

class f(sy.Function):
    def inverse(self, argindex=1):
        return g

x, y = sy.symbols('x y')
print sy.solve(y - f(x), x) # [g(y)] - correct
```

But if I try to evaluate **f(g(x))** sympy doesnt simplify this:

```
print f(g(x))               # f(g(x))
print f(g(x)).doit()        # f(g(x)) - why not x?
print f(g(x)).simplify()    # f(g(x)) - why not x?
```

**Question**: how to say to sympy that **f(g(x))** is just **x**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`inverse` isn't implemented to do that. I opened https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/10487 for it.  Ideally what I write below should work by default.

You can easily make it work by defining `_eval_simplify`, like

```
class f(sy.Function):
    def inverse(self, argindex=1):
        return g

    def _eval_simplify(self, ratio, measure):
        if isinstance(self.args[0], self.inverse()):
            return self.args[0].args[0]
        return self
```

If you have many classes you want to do this with you can put that in a superclass.

```
In [30]: f(g(x))
Out[30]: f(g(x))

In [31]: f(g(x)).simplify()
Out[31]: x
```

Or if you prefer for `doit()` to do it you can define `doit()`.